# Visual Studio Community 2015 C++ Запуск проектов на другом ПК

Tags: c, visual-studio

Всем привет.
В общем такая проблема. Использую VS Community 2015. Создаю проект, компилирую, все работает, но при запуске *.exe файла на другом ПК(на котором отсутствует VS Community), возникает ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поиск по гуглу, в общем то ничего не дал, единственное, что узнал *D.dll означает дебаговую версию(если я правильно выражаюсь). Использовал Release, ошибка не "устранилась". Прошу помощи. Ставить на другой ПК этот VS не вариант.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Установка на целевом компьютере VCREDIST нужной версии или статическая линковка проекта спасут вас. А еще вы даете дебажную сборку, но проблема вероятно не в этом.

Comment: Ну или можно просто тащить с собой нужную DLL.

Comment: @VladD Подумывал об этом, но по-моему это дико =)

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов Погуглил касательно статической линковки в VS, так и не понял как это сделать в Community. Точней говоря, не нашел нужной информации.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов Нашел в настройках проекта "Библиотека времени выполнения" Изначально стоял параметр "Многопоточный DLL (/MD)", сейчас выставил "Многопоточная (/MT)". Не знаю решает ли проблему, возможности проверить нет.

Comment: Кстати говоря *.exe существенно прибавил в весе.

Comment: @John установкой параметра /MD вы и сделали статическую компоновку. Верное решение - ставить VCREDIST, прочие решения - жуткие костыли.

Comment: @VladD - эта DLL в разных версиях windows может быть разная, и получится натуральный DLL HELL.

Comment: @gbg: DLL Hell не будет, если таскать библиотеку с собой, и держать в каталоге с приложением, локально.

Comment: @VlaD - она может линковаться с другими DLL.

Comment: @gbg: Ну, конкретно эта (рантайм C++) нормально живёт с системными библиотеками и больше ничего не требует. В общем случае нужно все нестандартные библиотеки, конечно, таскать с собой.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение. Надеюсь поможет тем кто столкнулся с этой же проблемой.
В свойствах проекта "C/C++ => Создание кода => Библиотека времени выполнения" Параметр "Многопоточный DLL (/MD)" заменяем на "Многопоточная (/MT)".

Comment: Статическая линковка, о которой я и говорил выше.

Comment: При статической линковке сборка будет происходить гораздо дольше. Я думаю, что лучше всё-таки на целевой компьютер устанавливать vcredist. Это номальная практика, и при установке многих приложений можно увидеть, что там сначала устанавливается vcredist.

Comment: @maestro отличная практика когда приложение просто должно работать, да...

Answer (score 0):

Установка на целевом компьютере VCREDIST нужной версии помогло, а вот статическая линковка нет. И пришлось несколько сторонних dll положить рядом со своим exe. Так и не нашел способа засунуть их внутрь exe.