# Где найти библиотеки, подключаемые по умолчанию, в Visual Studio? (С++)

Tags: c++

Насколько я понимаю, Visual Studio подключает некоторые библиотеки по умолчанию, даже если они не описаны в программе, и в другой среде программа может и не скомпилироваться. Где найти эти библиотеки, и как отключить их, чтобы быть уверенным, что программа запустится у другого человека?

Допустим, функция rand, вроде как, есть в библиотеках cstdlib и random, но её почему-то можно вызвать и без подключения этих библиотек.

Comment: `cstdlib` и `random` - это не библиотеки, а заголовочные файлы стандартной библиотеки, идущей вместе с компилятором. А для использования `rand` требуется подключить `stdlib.h` Visual Studio ничего по-умолчанию не подключает. Скорее даже наоборот, по какой-то причине регулярно появляются вопросы "как подключить библиотеку".

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Visual Studio Community 2015 C++ Запуск проектов на другом ПК](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526866/visual-studio-community-2015-c-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%9f%d0%9a)

Comment: @user7860670, STL -- это набор библиотек, библиотека библиотек, также как Boost. Вот они все https://en.cppreference.com/w/. Filesystem library, Thread support library, String library...

Comment: @megorit STL это Stepanov's Template Library - библиотека шаблонов от Александра Степанова. Она давно стала частью стандарта и отдельно уже практически не используется. А всякие randrom string и т.п. - это части стандартной библиотеки С++.

Comment: @user7860670, STL -- Standard Template Library. Её как раз по отдельности используют. Если не нужны потоки, то вы их не подключаете.

Comment: @megorit Как я уже написал выше, при использовании любого компонента это будет использованием компонента стандартной библиотеки. Никакого "набора" в духе boost нет.